# One web application or multiple web applications when using multiple databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, web-applications, web

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application hosted on IIS which will be using multiple databases on a single SQL Server 2014 instance (each database for a different company). The web application will be used for analysing and summing large amounts of business data.

What is the best practice in this kind of situation? Will there be performance issues if only one web application and pool is used with multiple databases? One database may have 1-20 users.

Which one would be a better choice, A or B?

A) 1 web application and 10 databases

B) 10 web applications and 10 databases

Comment: One has no bearing on the other. Functionally, it doesn't matter whether your application connects to one database or 1000. The performance is limited only by the individual performance of each database, not how many databases are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't belong to **MVC** at all.

If you have large amounts of data and you worry about performance, then you should think about how to store and query data at the database level. And you may interested in this kind of questions:

1. What provider use to query data? (pure ADO.NET or an ORM like Linq-to-SQL or EF)
2. Should I have all databases in one SQL Server instance, or can I use linked servers or even union data on web server side?
3. Should I have my databases files on different hard drives?

Answering these questions:

1. ADO.NET is always faster than ORMs just because they all use ADO.NET at their core. But it's harder to maintain ADO.NET queries in future
2. Linked servers are slower especially if you have your database on different machines (you will transfer your data by net and it is not fast if the is a large amount of data)
3. In the performance way it's better when your database files stored on different hard drives

Answer to your question now will be obvious, I think :)

Create one web application.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm using ADO.NET, one SQL Server instance, and the RAID 1 configuration on the server. I was just interested whether the web application may get overloaded if hundreds of users are using only one web application/pool with multiple databases.

Comment: there is no problem there as i mention.

Comment: Also, if talking about your problem further, don't you want to create data warehouse? I think Analisys services in MS SQL can help you with it. It also can be that it will be easier to create analitycs and statistic reports with this tool.

Comment: I'm using Highcharts Javascript API (http://www.highcharts.com/) for displaying statistics in a browser after data has been fetched (AJAX/JSON) from a server. So far this approach has worked.

Comment: I understand that it works, but you should understand that is you manibulate data to get some sort of statistical analys on client (with your js library) you send all db data by net. And that can became most tight place in your application where will be perfomance issues in future. But offcourse it's up to you do decide how to architecture your system.